# Im trying to set up an NSTimer that is connected to an image so that it is only valid while it isn't interacting with another image

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer

In the .h file I set up the `Goodguy`, `Building1` and `2`, the `NSTimer`, and the `falldown` method.

```
IBOutlet UIImageView *Goodguy;
IBOutlet UIImageView *Building1;
IBOutlet UIImageView *Building2;
NSTimer *GoodguyFall;

-(void)falldown;
```

In the .m file I set up the `GoodguyFall` `NSTimer`, and the code for when an image touches another image it will invalidate the `NSTimer`. How do I set it up so the timer is valid while it isn't touching the "buildings"?

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    GoodguyFall = [ NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 0.03 target:self selector:@selector(falldown) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}

-(void)falldown{
    Goodguy.center = (CGPointMake(Goodguy.center.x, Goodguy.center.y + 6));
}

    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(Goodguy.frame, Building1.frame)){
        [GoodguyFall invalidate];
    }
    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(Goodguy.frame, Building2.frame)){
        [GoodguyFall invalidate];
    }
}
```

Comment: Please describe the results that you are receiving from the code that you have posted.

Comment: the goodguy doesn't fall after it touches building1, how do i make the goodguy fall after it interacts with each building @DanielZhang

Answer (score 0):

To get the `Goodguy` to fall again after not touching a building, you’ll need to schedule another timer. This can be accomplished by

```
-(void)BuidlingMoving{
    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(Goodguy.frame, Building1.frame)){
        [GoodguyFall invalidate];
        GoodguyFall = nil;
    }
    else if (CGRectIntersectsRect(Goodguy.frame, Building2.frame)){
        [GoodguyFall invalidate];
        GoodguyFall = nil;
    } else if (GoodguyFall == nil) {
        GoodguyFall = [ NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 0.03 target:self selector:@selector(falldown) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    }
}
```

In this solution, I’m handling the case where `Goodguy` is no longer in contact with a building.

Comment: i don't know where i would put the timer again, i want the goodguy to fall while he is not interacting with the buildings, what should i do? @DanielZhang

Comment: Tell me what happens when the goodguy touches the building. From your code, the goodguy stops and nothing happens. What do you want to happen? How does the goodguy continue moving?

Comment: the goodguy never moves, unless he falls. The buildings move. i didn't put the code for the buildings to move up, do you want me too? @DanielZhang

Comment: @a.rabin I updated my answer to handle restarting the timer if the `Goodguy` is not in contact with a building. If this works I don't need to see further code.

Comment: basically i want the goodguy to be "running" on top of the buildings and if he isn't interacting with the buildings, i want him to fall @DanielZhang

Comment: @a.rabin I see. Can you post the code that moves the buildings?